# Совместная работа двух скриптов

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Добрый день всем!)

На странице есть меню:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jq.js"></script">
    ...
       <ul>
  <li>
    <a class="ul" href="javascript:ShowOrHide('category1')">1 уровень</a>
    <div id="category1" style="display:none">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="chernigiv/ch.htm">2 уровень</a></li>
            <li><a href="chernigiv/val.htm">2 уровень</a></li>
        ................
        <li><a href="chernigiv/val.htm">2 уровень</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Также на странице находится галерея:

```
<link href="../css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<!--запуск галереи-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#gallery a").lightBox();
});
</script>
</head>
...

 <a href="../img/6.jpg"><img src="../img/6m.jpg" height="90px" width="120px" alt=""/></a>
<a href="../img/2_2(387).jpg"><img src="../img/2_2m.jpg" height="90px" width="120px" alt=""/></a>

...
```

Вот такая проблема: когда тестил меню на отдельной странице, все ОК, так же и с галереей, вставил оба на одну страницу - ссылки меню не работают(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего переопределяется jquery. Нужно подключить в правильном порядке

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jq.js"></script">
```

Если галерея на прототайпе - то используй `$.noConflict()` 
[и дальше так](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: В такой последовательности (см. ниже)) работает галерея(а меню нет(
<!--скрипт для меню-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jq.js"></script>

 <!--стили та скрипты для галереи-->
 <link href="../css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
  
<!--запуск галереи-->
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 jQuery(function(){
     jQuery("a").lightBox();
});
</script>

Comment: В такой последовательности (см. ниже)) - работает меню(а галерея - нет(
<!--стили та скрипты для галереи-->
<link href="../css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<!--скрипт для меню-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jq.js"></script>

<!--запуск галереи-->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(function(){
 jQuery("a").lightBox();});</script>

Comment: Решыл так:

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.noConflict( );
    jQuery("a[href$=.jpg],a[href$=.png],a[href$=.gif]").lightBox();
 });
    </script>